# How to get a single line in a query SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains order numbers and order States (IN_PROGRESS, CANCELED, READY_FOR_PROC). I need to write a query that would return any single string in the state READY_FOR_PROC.The problem is that this query will be executed by multiple threads. And everyone should get a record that has not yet been processed by other threads (without duplicates).I tried to do this with `SELECT FOR UPDATE skip locked` and `rownum=1`, but then all executed queries except one return empty (if the first thread blocked the record for a long time). How do I write such a query?
I use Oracle if it's important

Comment: Your question is unclear. So some data and what you have tried and what is expectation

Answer (score 0):

Change your skip locked slightly to do this:

```
cursor C is SELECT ... FROM ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

then in your code, you just fetch

```
FETCH C INTO ...
```

It is the rownum=1 that is causing your issue.